# SQL - Reset sequence every 00h

Tags: sql, sequence

i have a .net program that based on the partnumber it creates a sequence  (if a sequence exists and if not he creates one).

he creates the sequence with the name "seq_partnumber"

example: seq_345765ab , seq_45123trw

i create a job to reset every sequence at midnight

```
alter sequence Seq_345765ab
restart with 1
alter sequence Seq_45123trw
restart with 1
alter sequence Seq_98234hjb
restart with 1
```

what i want to know if it's possible to reset like this

```
alter sequence Seq_*

restart with 1
```

or another way that i can automatize the reset of  every sequence the program create.

now i have to add manually every sequence that is created

Comment: In general, databases that support sequences support cycles in the sequence values, which appears to be what you want.  Without a database tag, it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: I guess it's about Postgresql, right?